Why is it I don't get pwd result from this dart code?
I'd like to get the result of my command line 'pwd' from my Dart console program.
I wait for the process to start, install the listeners and wait for the task to complete.
I don't get the result though.
I guess that waiting for the first line makes the pwd to be executed BEFORE the listener could get a change to be installed.
I my guess is true, how can I rewrite the code then?
    var process = await Process.start('pwd', []);
    process.stdout.listen((data) {
      print('stdout: $data');
    });
    process.stderr.listen((data) {
      print('stderr: $data');
    });
    int exitCode = await process.exitCode;


To print the current path it might be easier to use Process.run. Awaiting this function you get an object of type ProcessResult:
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  final processResult = await Process.run('pwd', []);
  print(processResult.stdout);
  print('Exit code: ${processResult.exitCode}');
}


To make your original approach work, you would have to decode stdout:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final process = await Process.start('pwd', []);

  process.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((data) {
    print('Stdout: $data');
  }).onDone(() async {
    // Delay printing the exit code until after the stream has closed.
    final exitCode = await process.exitCode; 
    print('Exit code: $exitCode');
  });
}

